# Sending a message between father & son - why there is no deadlock?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

Given this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
        int     fd[2], nbytes;
        pid_t   childpid;
        char    string[] = "Hello, world! I'm the son and this my message!\n";
        char    readbuffer[80];

        pipe(fd);   // piping fd[0] & fd[1]

        if((childpid = fork()) == -1)   // here we create a SON process
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(childpid == 0)    // child process
        {
                /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
                close(fd[0]);       // closing the READ end from reading , after that the SON would write into fd[1]

                /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
                write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
                printf("Verification : Message was sent successfully by the SON!\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        else    // father process
        {
                /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
                close(fd[1]);

                /* Read in a string from the pipe */
                nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
                printf("I'm the father and I received that string: %s", readbuffer);
        }

        return(0);
}
```

The output is :

```
I'm the father and I received that string: Hello, world! I'm the son and this my message!
Verification : Message was sent successfully by the SON!
```

I'm trying to understand pipes , and few things are not clear to me :

1. If the son sends his message in that line `write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));` and after that we have the `printf` that verifies that the message was sent, why am I getting the verification (e.g. `Verification : Message was sent successfully by the SON!`
   ) **after** the father received the message from the son ? wasn't it suppose to be **first** the **verification** from the son and only then the string ?
2. If the father tries to read from the pipe and the son want to write to the pipe , somewhere here hides (I think) a deadlock , doesn't ? why am I not getting a deadlock ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The reason the message from the child process comes later is because writing to a pipe can block until there is sufficient space in the buffer (from [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pipe.7.html)):

> If a process attempts to write to a full pipe (see
>          below), then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has been read from the pipe
>          to allow the write to complete.

So in other words the child process waits for the parent process to read the message within the call to `write()`.

2) If the child process fails to write anything to the pipe, then yes the parent will block (it won't deadlock as such).

Comment: Though pipe buffers under Linux are 16 kiB, which should be plenty for holding a 48-byte message (so it should really _never_ block in this example). I think it's really just a scheduling/concurrency artefact.

Comment: @Damon Yeah that certainly seems probable.

Answer (score 3):

Your first question:

`1. wasn't it suppose to be first the verification from the son and only then the string ?`

Answer: When you have more than one process running then the execution sequence of instructions of those processes is not deterministic. It depends on the scheduler which process gets scheduled when. So from the output of your program, we can tell the instruction execution sequence as follows:

`CHILD-PROCESS:`  write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1)); \\after this instruction this process gets suspended

`PARENT-PROCESS:` nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

`PARENT-PROCESS:` printf("I'm the father and I received that string: %s", readbuffer);

`CHILD-PROCESS:`  printf("Verification : Message was sent successfully by the SON!\n");

This sequence can be different as well some other-time.

Your secod question:

`2. Why am I not getting a deadlock ?`

Answer: In this situation, parent process just blocks waiting for some input on the pipe. But child can write, it does not have to wait. So there is no chance of deadlock.

Comment: Thanks ,can you give me an example when there is a deadlock ?

Answer (score 2):

Because of I/O buffering, there is no guarantee that the output will be displayed in the order it was printed.

Comment: +1 I was just going to say that's incorrect in this case, but after reading again... maybe if you reword it very slightly, it's _quite_ correct. There is no buffering going on during `write` on the pipe. However, `printf` like all C standard lib I/O certainly buffers. Since `printf` already executes after `write` anyway, the added uncertainity from buffering does not affect their order, though. Still, the other thread also uses `printf` so one could arguably say you're right (or at least, not wrong). But it's equally (or more?) likely that it's simply a scheduling artefact, really.

Answer (score 1):

When the child writes to the pipe, kernel changes the parent to running state. 
Seems that scheduler switch the parent to running, before the child prints the text (probably before child returns from `write` call).

So the line

```
printf("I'm the father and I received that string: %s", readbuffer);
```

is executed before line:

```
printf("Verification : Message was sent successfully by the SON!\n");
```

You can verify this by using `strace -f` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(childpid == 0)    // child process
    {
            write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1)); #C1
            printf("Verification : Message was sent successfully by the SON!\n"); #C2
            exit(0);
    }
    else    // father process
    {
            /* Read in a string from the pipe */
            nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer)); #F1
            printf("I'm the father and I received that string: %s", readbuffer); F2
    }
```

In the above case, we can't tell for sure whether **C1 or F1** will occur first. It depends on kernel scheduling and shouldn't be relied on. But both **C1 & F1** are related, if pipes are in bock mode. Related=**both has to happen, otherwise there will be a dead-lock**. Following situations would result in deadlock.

1. child not executing C1, but doing something else like wait for input etc & doesn't return, then parent will be dead-locked in F1.
2. parent not executing F1, but doing something else like wait for input etc & doesn't return, then child will be dead-locked in C1.

If either child/parent exits, then you would get a broken-pipe/sig-pipe i reckon.